# How to bootstrap the correlation via boot::boot() for multiple pairs of variables at the same time?

Tags: r, correlation

I have to calculate a lot of bootstrapped correlations (Pearson r). My knowledge of R (not to speak of writing my own functions) is limited. So far, I have only managed to calculate each bootstrapped correlation individually via `boot::boot()`, which is quite time intensive due to the high number of correlations.

**How do I calculate several bootstrapped correlations at the same time?**

**Here is the code I've been working with successfully, i.e. calculating each correlation individually.** This means I would have to repeat this code around 300 times, exchanging small parts of the code each time.

```
bootPearsonSZ <- function(data,i){
  cor(BdSZ$ndh[i],BdSZ$nkr_erst[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") # BdSZ = name of the data tibble I'm working with 
}
set.seed(1)
boot_PearsonSZ <- boot(BdSZ, bootPearsonSZ, 10000)
boot_PearsonSZ

mean(boot_PearsonSZ$t) #Shows me the bootstrapped value for Pearson r
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_PearsonSZ, type = "all", conf = 0.99) #Shows me the 99% conf. intervall
```

**Here is the code I unsuccessfully used to calculate at least some of the correlations at once. The code is not working correctly:** The output of `boot()` only shows me the correlation for the last line in my function, i.e. `cor(BdSZ$ndh[i],BdSZ$azr[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson")`

```
bootPearsonSZ <- function(data,i){
  cor(BdSZ$ndh[i],BdSZ$nkr_erst[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") # BdSZ = name of the data tibble I'm working with
  cor(BdSZ$ndh[i],BdSZ$nkr_ge[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson")
  cor(BdSZ$ndh[i],BdSZ$nkr_an[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson")
  cor(BdSZ$ndh[i],BdSZ$azr[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") #Apparently only the last line of code will be used by boot() 
}
set.seed(1)
boot_PearsonSZ <- boot(BdSZ, bootPearsonSZ, 10000)
boot_PearsonSZ

mean(boot_PearsonSZ$t)
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_PearsonSZ, type = "all", conf = 0.99)
```

**Additional info, that might be relevant to answering my question:**
I have both cross-sectional and longitudinal date. I want to calculate the correlations for 4x7 = 28 pairs of variables.
For the cross-sectional part of my study I have to calculate them for 3 city districts + all districts together, which leads me to perform 28x4 = 112 correlations.
For the longitudinal data I have one district but 7 years (+ all years together), which leads me to perform 28x(7+1) = 224 correlations.

Before calculating the correlations, I currently create a subset of my tibble each time, which only contains the district or year for which I want to calculate the bootstrapped correlation. Maybe there is a possibility to work around this by using the subsetting within the function I have written (and thus making it simpler)?

I'm very gratefull for any sort of help!

---

EDIT: Added reproducible example as asked for by @stephan-kolassa:

```
library(boot)
library(tidyr)
library(faux)

IndependentVariables <- rnorm_multi(n = 30,
                  mu = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100),
                  sd = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
                  r = 0.25,
                  varnames = c("IV1", "IV2", "IV3", "IV4", "IV5", "IV6", "IV7"),
                  empirical = FALSE)

DependentVariable <- rnorm_multi(n = 30,
                  mu = c(100, 100, 100, 100),
                  sd = c(10, 10, 10, 10),
                  r = 0.6,
                  varnames = c("DV1", "DV2", "DV3", "DV4"),
                  empirical = FALSE)

ID <- c(1:30)

mydata <- cbind(ID, IndependentVariables, DependentVariable)

bootPearson <- function(data,i){
  cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV1[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") 
  cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV2[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") 
  cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV3[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") 
  cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV4[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") 
  cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV5[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") 
  cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV6[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") 
  cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV7[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson") 
}
set.seed(1)
boot_Pearson <- boot(mydata, bootPearson, 2000)
boot_Pearson

mean(boot_Pearson$t) #Shows me the bootstrapped value for Pearson r
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_Pearson, type = "all", conf = 0.99) #Shows me the 99% conf. intervall
```

Comment: This should not be overly complicated, although it is off-topic here, as mainly programming-related. If you could edit your post to include a Minimal Working Example, we can migrate this to StackOverflow (and potentially also answer it). The key thing will be to collect everything you want to correlate in one big matrix, and if you then want to correlate all pairs of columns, simply wrapping `cor` in `boot` will work. (`boot` will flatten the output into one matrix instead of a 3d array, so you will need to tease it apart again.)

Comment: Thank you @StephanKolassa I tried to create a reproducible example the best I could and added it to my post. I hope this is sufficient for further clarification. However I don't know how to migrate the post to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks! I hope my answer helps. I'll still vote to close the question and migrate it to SO, just to keep the site tidy. You should see a little "flag" link below your question where you can flag it for moderator attention and request migration to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bootPearson()` function does not do what you presumably want it to do. Right now, it calculates seven different correlations *but only returns the last one* - everything else gets calculated and discarded. In R, functions only return the last result created in the function body. You may want to read up on how R functions work.

The solution is simple: just change `bootPearson()` to create and return a single object - namely, a vector of length 7 that contains the seven correlations you calculate. Concatenate them into one vector using the `c()` command:

```
bootPearson <- function(data,i){
    c(cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV1[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson"), 
        cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV2[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson"), 
        cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV3[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson"), 
        cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV4[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson"),
        cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV5[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson"), 
        cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV6[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson"), 
        cor(mydata$DV1[i],mydata$IV7[i], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson")) 
}
```

Of course, you can now also loop over your DVs and IVs within this function and fill the results vector (using a counter to point at the correct entry) - no need to copy 28 almost identical lines.

```
bootPearson <- function(data,i){
    result <- rep(NA,28)
    pointer <- 1
    for ( iv in 1:7 ) {
        for ( dv in 1:4 ) {
            result[pointer] <- cor(mydata[i,iv+1],mydata[i,dv+8], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson")
            pointer <- pointer+1
        }
    }
    result
}
```

Note how the final `result` makes the function return the entire vector.

Comment: Thank your so very much, @StephanKolassa!!! I really do appreciate your help, espacially since I feel that I now got a better understanding of how functions work (which the book I've been working with only spend one page on).

Comment: Quick addition, in case someone stumble opon this post and is struggling with the same issues. The following code can be used to receive the bootstrapped Pearson r as well as the bootstrapped confidence intervalls:

**mean(boot_Pearson$t[,1])** #Shows the value for the first bootstrapped Pearson r in the list of 28 calculated values.      

**boot.ci(boot.out = boot_Pearson, index = 1, type = "bca", conf = 0.99)** #Shows the values of the bootstrapped confidence interval for the aforementioned Pearson r (index from 1:28)